# How do I order an IEnumerable<T> such that a special item is always at the bottom?

Tags: c#

I have an `IEnumerable<string>` being passed to me which has the following items:

- HP
- Canon
- Lexmark
- Samsung
- Other

Now what I am trying to achieve is order the items alphabetically but I want to keep the `other` item last. I have gone ahead and used `OrderBy(i => i)`

which lists the items as follows:

- Canon
- HP
- Lexmark
- Other
- Samsung

The desired result I want is

- Canon
- HP
- Lexmark
- Samsung
- Other

I have tried using `.OrderBy(i => i != "Other").ThenBy(i => i)` but this puts `Other` item right at the top.

Can someone tell me how to achieve this please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use `OrderByDescending` because `true` is "higher" than `false`

```
list.OrderByDescending(s => s != "Other")
    .ThenBy(s => s);
```

You could also use

```
list.OrderBy(s => s == "Other" ? 1 : 0)
    .ThenBy(s => s);
```

Since you have asked, here are extension methods which simplify it for future use:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> OrderFirst<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence, Func<T, bool> predicate)
{
    return sequence.OrderByDescending(predicate);
}

public static IEnumerable<T> OrderLast<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence, Func<T, bool> predicate)
{
    return sequence.OrderBy(predicate);
}
```

Example usage:

```
var list = new List<string> { "HP", "Other", "Samsung" };
var otherLast = list.OrderLast(s => s == "Other").ToList();
```

Comment: Thank for this. How would I turn it into an extension method becuase I will be doing it with a few other `IEnumerable<T>`

Comment: Or (just because it's slightly shorter) `list.OrderBy(s => s == "Other").ThenBy(s => s);`

Comment: @Code you don't need to do anything. You can use multiple fields with `OrderBy`, just like `Select`. If you use an expression in `OrderBy` that returns `(s=="Other",s)` or `Tuple.Create(s=="Other",s)`, you'll achieve what you want. It's equivalent to SQL's `ORDER BY a,b,c`

Comment: @MatthewWatson not shorter than `list.OrderBy(s=>(s=="Other",s))`, or the equivalent with Tuple.Create. I wonder what the performance difference would be though. Copying vs allocations vs (possibly) multiple iterations?

Comment: You've got a good point i'll stick with this

Answer (score 4):

> I have tried using `.OrderBy(i => i != "Other").ThenBy(i => i)` but this puts Other item right at the top.

So you're almost there, you just need to reverse the sort order of your first criterion: Replace `OrderBy` by `OrderByDesc` **or** replace `i != "Other"` with `i == "Other`.

Of course, it does not hurt to be explicit: It's not obvious how Booleans are sorted, so I'd prefer:

```
.OrderBy(i != "Other" ? 1 : 2).ThenBy(i => i);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help

Answer (score 4):

Another option using tuples:

```
list.OrderBy(s => Tuple.Create(s=="Other",s));
```

or, in C# 7 :

```
list.OrderBy(s => (s=="Other",s));
```

OrderBy expects an expression that returns the *key* by which to sort. If you want to sort by multiple fields, you need to return an object or tuple that contains the field's values. It's no different than `Select()`.

Tuples are needed because they already implement IComparable. Returning an anonymous object would fail because it doesn't implement this interface

Comment: Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 //Imagining your list like this :
 var myList = new List<string>() {"HP", "Canon", "Lexmark", "Samsung", "Other"};

  var other = myList.Where(ro => ro == "Other").FirstOrDefault();
  myList.Remove(other);
  var finalList = myList.OrderBy(ro => ro).ToList();
  finalList.Add(other);
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: *Modifying* the original data isn't a good idea when talking about *sorting*

Comment: Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this by adding the "Other" at the end after the Order By:

```
 IEnumerable<string> lst = new string[]
      {
         "HP", "Canon", "Lexmark", "Samsung", "Other"
      };

 lst = lst.Select(x => x).Where(x => x != "Other").OrderBy(x => x).ToList();
 lst = lst.Concat(new string[] {"Other"}).ToList();
```

Or in short:

```
lst = lst.Select(x => x).Where(x => x != "Other").OrderBy(x => x).Concat(new string[] {"Other"}).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for your help